Array Operations in Genetic Algorithms
I've been trying to implement simple Gen. Algorithm but I can't wrap my head around splitting up an array into pieces and assigning that to the new array.
My problems:
1.I don't know how to split rows one by one into pieces and then assigning those array pieces into new (1) row of some other matrix.
for (int i = 0; i < P; i++)
{
    int split = random.Next(P);
    int split2 = population[i].Length-split;
    int[] firstHalf = new int[split];
    int[] secondHalf = new int[split2];

    Array.Copy(population[i], 0, firstHalf, 0, split);
    Array.Copy(population[i], split, secondHalf, 0, split2);
    int[] combined = new int[split + split2];
    Array.Copy(firstHalf, combined, split);
    Array.Copy(secondHalf, 0, combined, split, split2);

    for(int j = 0;j <P; j++)
    {
        children[j] = combined[j];
    }
}

It does not compile at
children[j] = combined[j];

it says that it can't convert int to int[] which surprises me but it isn't the biggest problem since I know that this approach does not make sense and even if it did it would not be optimal at  all.
Even without this and assigning
children[i] = combined

it does compile but during the iteration of the children array I get System.Int32[] instead of the actual value but I also understand this because I assign object array to children[i] (I think at least).
The problem is that I can't think of any other way of doing this.
2. The algorithm includes splitting 2 rows and combining them into 2 children. 1 children is made of  gens of parent1 and parent2.
Which also baffles me in terms of coding this into some kind of nested loop.
The whole code for reference:
int P = 10;
int fit = 0;
int[] fittness=new int[P];
Random random = new Random();
int[] ideal = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
int[][] children = new int[P][];
int[][] population= new int[P][];
//generating population
for (int i=0;i < P;i++)
{
    population[i] = new int [P];
    for (int j=0;j<P;j++)
    {
        population[i][j] = random.Next(2);
    }
}
//fittness
for (int i = 0; i < P; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < P; j++)
    {
        if (population[i][j] == ideal[j])
            fit++;
    }
    fittness[i] = fit;
    fit = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < P; i++)
{
    int split = random.Next(P);
    int split2 = population[i].Length-split;
    int[] firstHalf = new int[split];
    int[] secondHalf = new int[split2];

    Array.Copy(population[i], 0, firstHalf, 0, split);
    Array.Copy(population[i], split, secondHalf, 0, split2);
    int[] combined = new int[split + split2];
    Array.Copy(firstHalf, combined, split);
    Array.Copy(secondHalf, 0, combined, split, split2);
    children[i] = combined;
}

for (int i = 0; i < P; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < P; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(" "+population[i][j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($" => {fittness[i]}");
}
Console.WriteLine("Children:");
for (int i = 0; i < P; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < P; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(" " + children[i]);
    }
}

I've been trying to solve this by myself for quite a bit and consulted internet resources

You declared children as int[][] children. Therefore, each element children[i] is an integer array int[], but you are trying to assign it an int element from combined which is declared as int[] combined in your first code snippet:
//    int[]          int
//  ____^____     ____^____
// /         \   /         \
   children[j] = combined[j];

Later you do the right assignemet:
//    int[]       int[]
//  ____^____     __^___
// /         \   /      \
   children[i] = combined;

Why are you getting System.Int32[] instead of the actual value then? Well, C# cannot directly print an array. Instead, it just prints its type name. If you want to print an array, you can either use a loop, or join the values into a string:
string s = String.Join(", ", children);
Console.WriteLine(s);

Prints e.g.: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13
